# CountDownTimer cancel() doesn't cancel the timer and continue working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, countdowntimer

I'm using CountDownTimer class to update firebase realtime database, but cancel() method seems doesn't work.

I want when the timer finishes to call fetchUserPoints() and to add the points itself.

Could you help me, please?

```
int time = 6;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


private void timeDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvTimer.setText("0:" + checkDigit(time));
                time--;

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tvTimer.setText("Time finished");
                fechUserPoints();
            }


        }.start();
    }

    public String checkDigit(int number) {
        return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
    }

    private void fetchUserPoints() {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        reference.child(mId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                prevPoints = dataSnapshot.child("points").getValue().toString();
                int prePoints = Integer.valueOf(prevPoints);
                String newPoints = String.valueOf(prePoints + ADDED_POINTS);

                reference.child(mId).child("points").setValue(newPoints).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Process is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and here fetchUserPoints() continue calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cancel your CountDownTimer inside onFinish method. Try this

```
int time = 6;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;


private void timeDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvTimer.setText("0:" + checkDigit(time));
                time--;

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tvTimer.setText("Time finished");
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                fechUserPoints();
            }


        }.start();
    }

    public String checkDigit(int number) {
        return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
    }

    private void fetchUserPoints() {

        reference.child(mId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                prevPoints = dataSnapshot.child("points").getValue().toString();
                int prePoints = Integer.valueOf(prevPoints);
                String newPoints = String.valueOf(prePoints + ADDED_POINTS);

                reference.child(mId).child("points").setValue(newPoints).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Process is successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Another example see here it working

```
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    int time = 6;

    private void timeDownTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.e("TIK : " , checkDigit(time));
                time--;

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                test();
            }


        }.start();
    }

    public String checkDigit(int number) {
        return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
    }

    private void test(){
        Log.e("TIK : " , "inside my method");
        Toast.makeText(this,"on finish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: It should work. I've tested with another example, you can check my edited answer.

Comment: Here the test method will be called once on Finish of CountDownTimer

Comment: Thank you so muck bro, I figured out that fetchUserPoints() is the problem, your answer helped a lot, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Happy to help you and if you find this answer helpful please accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to maintain **CountDownTimer** as a method local variable and not as a global/class level variable, **because** if you trigger ***timeDownTimer()*** multiple time then the old reference of ***countDownTimer*** would be lost and you would not be able to cancel previous timers which were initiated.

I think that might can be a problem here.

Comment: Okay I did, but where exactly the right place to cancel the timer?

Comment: you can cancel in the same place where you are currently cancelling fetchUserPoints().

Comment: Thank you so muck bro, I figured out that fetchUserPoints() is the problem, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call **countDownTimer.cancel()** inside **fetchUserPoints()** since you call **fetchUserPoints()** inside **onFinish** method of **countDownTimer**; You are trying to cancel an ended process.

Comment: but the method doesn't stop to be called.

Comment: Is the countdowntimer stopped or it restart like a loop?

Comment: Thank you so muck bro, I figured out that fetchUserPoints() is the problem, I really appreciate your help.